# Implementing a XNOR Gate in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pycharm, sequence

I have a sequence of positive integers sorted in ascending order. 
I would like to determine if two integers **A and B** exist in the sorted **sequence** such that **A XNOR B = -1**, by ***comparing all possible pairs*** in the sorted sequence and check if they are **Exclusive NOR to -1**. I am unclear in implement logic gates so any help would be much appreciated!

```
sequence = [5, 5, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10]
```

Expected output:

> A=5, B=5 
>  A=8, B=8 
>  A=8, B=8 
>  A=8, B=8 
> **Total match is 4.**

Comment: In general there's no specific **XNOR** operator but given that XNOR is a logical complement of **XOR**  you can implement a logical gate as `~ (A ^ B)`

Comment: are you able to use bitwise operators to implement it?

Answer (score 3):

`a xnor b == -1` is the same thing as `a == b`, so:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> sequence = [5, 5, 8, 8, 8, 9, 10]
>>> matches = [(k, v) for k, v in combinations(sequence, 2) if k == v]
```

then

```
>>> matches
[(5, 5), (8, 8), (8, 8), (8, 8)]
```

and

```
>>> len(matches)
4
```